# ZFS does not mount on first boot

Tags: ubuntu, zfs

I have a Ubuntu 17.10 powered server with a separate root disk and one ZFS pool composed of three hard disks. Each time I start the server after it was properly powered off, the zpool does not automatically appear. However, if I reboot the server after its first boot, the ZFS pool gets automatically mounted and appears.

The setup is as follows:

```
$ sudo zpool status
NAME     SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
mydata  5.44T  2.88T  2.55T         -     8%    53%  1.00x  ONLINE  -

$ sudo zpool list
pool: mydata
state: ONLINE
scan: scrub repaired 0 in 10h33m with 0 errors on Mon Apr  2 00:53:06 2018
config:

    NAME                                    STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    mydata                                  ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz1-0                              ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-SAMSUNG_HD204UI_S2H7J9AB809595  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-SAMSUNG_HD204UI_S2H7J9JB808621  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-SAMSUNG_HD204UI_S2H7J90B833202  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

I've already tried to adjust `/etc/default/zfs` and set the mount option, unfortunately without success.

```
$ cat /etc/default/zfs | grep MOUNT
ZFS_MOUNT='yes'
ZFS_UNMOUNT='yes'
VERBOSE_MOUNT='no'
DO_OVERLAY_MOUNTS='no'
MOUNT_EXTRA_OPTIONS=""
ZFS_INITRD_PRE_MOUNTROOT_SLEEP='0'
```

Of course, all packages are up to date including ZFS. The system partition is not on the ZFS pool but on a separate disk:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem                       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                             1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                            393M  956K  392M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/mm--server--vg-root  2.9G  2.7G  121M  96% /
tmpfs                            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                        472M  194M  254M  44% /boot
```

I have spent some time researching the issue but this appears to be the opposite to the more common problems in which the pool does not persist over the reboot -- whilst in this case the pool only appears if I reboot the server but not on the first boot after the server was powered off. My problem is reproducible.

Any pointers to what the issue could be are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What disk controller are you using? If you have an ATTO controller, as I do, you may need to run the ATTO kernel driver install script:

```
Downloads/lnx_drv_esashba2_2300f1# ./install.sh

ATTO Technology, Inc.
Linux Driver Install Script v2.66

A conflict has been discovered with a third-party driver (pm80xx).

This could prevent the ATTO driver from operating properly.
You may uninstall the pm80xx driver here, although
any devices that depend on it will no longer function.
The driver module will be preserved and can be reinstalled if the 
esas2hba driver is uninstalled using the uninstall script.

Would you like to unload and uninstall pm80xx? [Y/n]
y
pm80xx backed up.

Building and installing the ATTO "ExpressSAS 6Gb HBA" driver, please wait...

Successfully installed the "ExpressSAS 6Gb HBA" driver
```